# php file_exists() return false on some directory on IIS

Tags: php

#### Environment:

1. php5
2. windows2003
3. IIS with fastCGI

#### Code:

```
<?php
$p = "i:\\tmp";
if( file_exists($p) )
{
    print $p . ' exists!';
}
else
{
    print $p . ' not exists!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you running a web server?

Comment: Considering your comments: are you absolutely 100% sure that the file is there and that your path to it is correct?
Also please post your exact code, I don't think we can provide any more help from the information you have provided so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it:

when use

```
file_exist()
```

to test an existing directory, if parent directory has no read permission of IUSR_MACHINE, the test always fails.

Comment: The `open_basedir` might be causing this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: open_basedir is not set in php.ini,

any idea where else such 'safty' limits can be given?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that directory is readable by checking it's permissions (chmod).

Alternatively, you might try using

```
is_readable()
```

function.

Comment: It's on windows. I add 'everyone' read/write permissions. not working.

Comment: is_readable() and is_dir() both always return false.

is_readable - "Tells whether a file exists and is readable." not sure if this will work on directory?

Answer (score 1):

what does your code looks like? if you're testing with a string literal, don't forget that backslashes introduce escape sequences:

```
file_exists("D:\rip\this\nipple")
```

here `\r` is a carriage return, `\t` a tab, and `\n` a line feed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP in safe mode then File_Exists will always return FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions.

Also note that the File_Exists caches it's result, so you might wan't to clear the cache with the [ClearStatCache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) function

Comment: thx!

safe mode is off in php.ini.

called ClearStatCache function.

still not working with both.